# DrRacket Contract Violation

Tags: racket

I installed DrRacket so I can learn programming concepts using SICP. But for the past week or so, every time I launch DrRacket the console windows comes up with the following message:

```
fl-:contract violation
  expected: flonum?
  given: 0
  argument position: 2nd
  other arguments...:
     2.0
```

I am not sure how I got here. I tried uninstalling and re-installing as 32-bit and 64-bit, restarting my laptop, searched forums for a possible fix. No luck. Just want to get back to my normal window where I can type in code. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Windows? If so what version? Else, are you using Linux? OSX? More info would be useful.

Comment: You can report it to [Racket Bug Reports](http://bugs.racket-lang.org/)

Answer (score 0):

hope u found the answer. For my case, I found out that from a file I had been working on, and my computer shut down unexpectedly, there were three files associated with the initial file name - upon resuming Windows. The file extensions were .rkt (original), .bak and .1. I renamed the '.1' file as a second copy of the original and the 'contract violation' problem ended. It appeared the '.1' file was due to the laptop shutdown and was the auto-retrieve file.